# HTTPClient for calling REST service is not working

Tags: c#, rest, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, async-await

I am trying to consume REST service which returns me the data in JSON format. And I am using simple logic. But code get stuck on the line . I have check this code from emulator as well as from Device. 
`var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);`

Here is my code

```
public async Task<string> GetMyData(string urlToCall)
        {    
            using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient())
            {                    
                HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(System.Net.Http.HttpMethod.Get, urlToCall);
                var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
                var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                return responseString;
            }
        }
```

and calling is like,

```
string result = GetMyData(url).Result;
```

Is I am missing something? I want to get the data synchronously, instead of WebClient I choose HTTPClient for synchronous data call.

Can anyone please suggest me any solution.

**EDIT**

Thanks @Mike Richards for pointing me in right direction
I want to achieve the flow like below,

Call from Main.xaml.cs for aunticateuser() -> calling aunticateuser() methode in Process Class-> once response get from service return control back to Main.xaml.cs -> naviagate to another page i.e. Dashboard.xaml

But in real case its working like, call going to aunticateuser() methode in Process Class and where its send request to service and coming back to Main.xaml.cs but not waiting there to listen the response so how I will decide is this user is valid or not until I get the response?

**Code**

```
    private void ApplicationBarDone_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                bool isValid = checkForValidation();

                if (isValid)
                {
                    string url = txtUrl.Text.ToString().TrimStart(' ').TrimEnd(' ');
                    string login = txtLogin.Text.ToString().TrimStart(' ').TrimEnd(' ');
                    string clientKey = txtSystemKey.Text.ToString().TrimStart(' ').TrimEnd(' ');
                    string psw = txtPassword.Text.ToString().TrimStart(' ').TrimEnd(' ');

                    RestfulWebServiceUserDAO userDAO = new RestfulWebServiceUserDAO();
                    userDAO.authenticateUser(login, psw, clientKey, url);
                   //navigate to another page  from here ??
                }
            }
```

In RestfulWebServiceUserDAO class authenticateUser() methode present

```
public async override void authenticateUser(string login, string password, string clientkey, string systemurl)
        {

            string url = systemurl + "/rest/user?login=" + login + "&password=" + password + "&clientkey=" + clientkey + "&languageId=" + 1;  

            string result = await GetMyData(url);
           //or shall I navigate from here?? this is not allowed :|
        }
```

GetMyData() methode same in RestfulWebServiceUserDAO class that what I have mark above.

Comment: Are you doing that in the UI thread?

Comment: @I3arnon No, I am not running this on UI thread?

Comment: Are you only using this method for synchronous calls only?

Comment: You can't do that asynchronously in Windows Phone. You'll need to be async all the way to the top. Where are you calling this from? An event handler? A command?

Comment: @PauloMorgado Do I need to start new thread for getting response from web service. My requirement is I am checking login validation from web service and I need to wait the user until response come from Service.

Comment: Can you show more code. The invocation chain and pertinent code only. Please don't post unrelated code.

Comment: Sure @PauloMorgado question is update can you please check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you go async, you need to go async all the way to the top. But you need to always return an awaitable (commonly a `Task`).

Exception made for event handlers and method overrides. But in this case those will be fire-and-forget.

What's hapening in your code is that, although inside your `authenticateUser` (which, by convention, should be called `AuthenticateUserAsync`) method you are awaiting for the result of GetMyData (again, `GetMyDataAsync`), you are not returning any awaitable results to the caller. Becaus aysnc methods return to the caller as soon as they hit the first `await` statement.

Because of that, when `ApplicationBarDone_Click` calls `userDAO.authenticateUser` it imediately returns because it's not awaitable.

If you can't change `authenticateUser`, you simply can't use `async-await`. But being Windows Phone, network calls need to be asynchronous and you need to change that. Being so, your `AuthenticateUserAsync` method (remember the convention?) should look something like this:

```
public async override Task<string> AuthenticateUserAsync(string login, string password, string clientkey, string systemurl)
{

    string url = systemurl + "/rest/user?login=" + login + "&password=" + password + "&clientkey=" + clientkey + "&languageId=" + 1;  

    return await GetMyDataAsync(url);
}
```

And your `ApplicationBarDone_Click` should look something like this:

```
private async void ApplicationBarDone_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bool isValid = checkForValidation();

    if (isValid)
    {
        string url = txtUrl.Text.ToString().TrimStart(' ').TrimEnd(' ');
        string login = txtLogin.Text.ToString().TrimStart(' ').TrimEnd(' ');
        string clientKey = txtSystemKey.Text.ToString().TrimStart(' ').TrimEnd(' ');
        string psw = txtPassword.Text.ToString().TrimStart(' ').TrimEnd(' ');

        RestfulWebServiceUserDAO userDAO = new RestfulWebServiceUserDAO();
        string result = await userDAO.AuthenticateUserAsync(login, psw, clientKey, url);

        // do whatever you need to do after login.
        // just remember that, during the call to userDAO.AuthenticateUserAsync
        // the UI is responsive and the user can click again
    }
}
```

To learn more about `asyn-await` programming, read [my curation](http://curah.microsoft.com/45553).

Comment: Oh what a mess I am doing. Thanks for giving such valuable information. As I am new to Windows Phone so not aware of network asynchronous calling. Thanks once again.

Comment: @gofor.net, you're forced into this on Silverlight, Windows Phone and Windows Runtime but that's the pattern you should follow for Windows Forms and WPF also.

Comment: can we do lockable await, as in same case I need to wait for my asynchronous task to complete, like create and delete database tables?

Comment: @gofor.net, can you explain a bit more what you want to do? `await` asynchronously waits for the task to end.

Comment: `public static async Task CreateDatabase()
        {
                string createTableQuery = Db.DBFileProcessClass.ReadDBFiles("Db/CreateTables.txt");
                await localDB.ExecuteStatementAsync(createTableQuery).AsTask().ConfigureAwait(false);      
}`

In this code, I want to be wait here until my table creation is done. **CreateTables.txt** is text file with list of create table statement(about 20 create table query.)

Comment: Isn't that what that code is doing? Asynchronously waiting for `localDB.ExecuteStatementAsync(createTableQuery)` to end?

Comment: its not waiting for execution of query (I am using sqlite wrapper) . Its sending back control to next process. CreateDatabase() written in App.xaml.cs

Comment: You can't do that. That would block the UI thread. Everything has been done to avoid that. Why do you think you need that?

Comment: Because after creation I want to insert the data into one of the table, and when I tried such with above method it sometimes give me error and sometime works smooth. I just got one reference from

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/UpdatingMyWindowsPhoneAppToWindowsPhone8.aspx

and http://qedcode.com/content/awaitable-critical-section. I am checking this.

Comment: You should be able to do that. Can you show that code?

Answer (score 1):

Try awaiting GetMyData

```
string result = await GetMyData(url)
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in right direction. Can you please check my edited question. What I exactly want from this process.